# List form criteria on the results web page

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion form where a user enters search criteria. After clicking submit it takes you to the results webpage.

I would like to list the search criteria on the results web page (kind of like a summary so the user knows what they just searched) in case they want to print the page.

I have included the image below of the devtools form data in the Results page, so the data is there. I'm just wondering do I need to create a new form or can I list the criteria as `<p>` tags?

[image]

Comment: Random recommendation: Consider using `<ul><li>` tags since this is an unordered list of form fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list = "#form.fieldnames#" index = "formField">
 <p>#formField# - #form[formField]#</p>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Add formatting as required.

**Edit**

Regarding the error you got with `#form[StateInput]#`, it was probably for an unknown variable.  You can either use dot notation, `#form.StateInput#`, or quote the name of the field, `#form['StateInput']#`.

Comment: Why did you replace `fieldnames` with `formnames` in the edit? There is no `form.formnames` in a POST.

Comment: And always encode user input, e.g. using `encodeForHtml(formField)` and `encodeForHtml(form[formField])`.

Comment: Thanks. I used the code from Matt, but replaced formnames with fieldnames as Alex suggested. formnames did not work. What if I want to only list certain fieldnames? I tried replacing the p tag with <p>#form[StateInput]#</p> but get an error.

Comment: If you want to list only certain form fields forget the loop and output just the fields you want to.

Comment: Ok thanks. On second thought, I think the loop will be good because it is only listing the form fields for which input criteria is present. I deleted the "#formField# -" portion of the p tag since I just want the data not the field names to be listed.